# Выдаёт ошибку после копирования динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Программа должна увеличить массив на 1 элемент и заполнить его значениями.В конце на cout'e выдаёт ошибку:string subscript out of range

```
struct book
{
string num;
string name;
string surname;
string city;
};
book* input(book*&m,int &size)
{
book*ptr=new book[++size]{};
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    ptr[i] = m[i];
cout << "Enter phone's number:";
cin >> ptr[size-1].num;
cout << "Enter Name:";
cin >> ptr[size - 1].name;
cout << "Enter surname:";
cin >> ptr[size - 1].surname;
cout << "Enter city:";
cin >> ptr[size - 1].city;
delete[]m;
m = nullptr;
return ptr;
}
void main()
{
int size = 1;
book *m = new book[size]{};
m=input(m, size);
cout << m->name[1] << "\t" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `void main()`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала вы создаете  массив из одного элемента. Все поля его пустые. При вызове `input` будет создан новый массив из двух элементов, причем первый так и останется пустым, а второй будет заполнен. Соответственно строка `m->name` будет пустая и обращение к символу со смещением 1 будет вне диапазона. Надо полагать, вместо `m->name[1]` надо было писать `m[1].name` чтобы обратится к только что заполненному элементу. А вообще лучше было бы использовать `std::vector`.

Comment: Спасибо.Что-то не подумал что квадратные скобки перед точкой а не в конце надо ставить

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = 0;
book *m = NULL;
m = input(m, size);
cout << m[0].name << "\t" << endl;

book* input(book*&m,int &size)
{
  ...
  if (m)
    delete[]m;
  ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался